# sdist error: option --manifest-only not recognized

Tags: python, sdist

Everytime I use sdist to creat the MANIFEST file with the command:

```
'python setup.py sdist --manifest-only'
```

The terminal always outputs this error msg.

> error: option --manifest-only not recognized

I don't know why and am looking for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you use

```
from setuptools import setup
```

in you setup.py ? Setuptools seems not to support this option. I prefer to stick to the standard Python way and use:

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

Comment: Amazing!!!  You are right. I'm using setuptools instead of distutils, but setuptools will generate SOURCES.txt instead of traditional MANIFEST file. Many thanks!!

Comment: Related: setuptools vs distutils http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337706/setuptools-vs-distutils-why-is-distutils-still-a-thing