# Deprecation warning in python

Tags: python

The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives

How to fix this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error but only a warning. It means the `distutils` package can still be used, but it's recommended to avoid it because of better alternatives. You can use the package `setuptools` instead, see more details in [PEP 632](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/) if you are interested or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337706/setuptools-vs-distutils-why-is-distutils-still-a-thing) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2).

Without code example it is impossible to help how exactly you should change your code to `setuptools`.